# Laravel form returning errors only for some fields in log file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I've got an application form. This form has a few fields, such as "name", "email", "country", etc.

Laravel is ONLY redirecting back returning an error for the email field. Such as `The email field is required.`. For everything else, it just refreshes the page, and in my `laravel.log` file, I get the following error:

> [2017-11-16 08:52:30] production.ERROR:
>   Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException: The given data failed to
>   pass validation. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\series\commend-me\CommendMe\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests.php:89

Here is my route:

```
Route::post('/postapply', [
    'uses' => '\CommendMe\Http\Controllers\ApplyController@postApply',
    'as' => 'post.apply',
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);
```

and my controller:

```
public function postApply(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|alpha_num|max:40|min:2',            
        'country' => 'required|alpha_num|max:100|min:2',                        
        'body' => 'required|string|max:2000',
        'mature' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
    ]);             



    dd("test");
```

dd does not return "test" in this instance. Furthermore, the validation will ONLY redirect back an error for the email field, and if the email field is renamed to something else in the controller, it'll go back to just sending the error to the log file.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

Adding markup as requested:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{ route ('post.apply') }}">
    <div class="submitArtSection">
    <div class="submitRequired submitRequiredTitle">Required</div>
        <div class="border-bot">
            <input class="submitArtTitle" type="text" name="name" maxlength="39"  placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    <div class="submitRequired submitRequiredTitle">Required</div>          
        <div class="border-bot">
            <input class="submitArtTitle" type="text" maxlength="255" name="email"  placeholder="Email">
        </div>      
    <div class="submitRequired submitRequiredTitle">Required</div>          
        <div class="border-bot">
            <input class="submitArtTitle" type="text" maxlength="255" name="country"  placeholder="Country">
        </div>  
    <div class="submitRequired submitRequiredTitle">Required</div>          
        <div>
            <textarea name="body" style="height: 175px;" maxlength="1980" placeholder="Tell us about yourself..."></textarea>       
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="submitArtSection submitArtCheckers">
    <div class="submitRequired">Required</div>
        <div>
            <span class="submitArtCaption submitArtRestrictionsHeader">
                Age
            </span>
            <span>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="mature" value="0">
                    Under 18
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>

                <label>
                 <input type="radio" name="mature" value="1">
                    18+
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>    
            </span>             
        </div>  
    </div>


    <div class="text-center">
        <button id="saveImage" class="pointer">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

dd($request->all()); at the start of the method returns of the following

```
array:5 [▼
  "name" => ""
  "email" => ""
  "country" => ""
  "body" => ""
  "_token" => "HKJ51CMvteYOD0OG79SQiRjpeTup9NNWvTfw1IWB"
]
```

Comment: Are you including a help-block for each of the inputs in the form? Maybe you only included it in the email input.

Comment: Can you show the code of your form that might help us find the problem.

Comment: add a `dd($request->all())` at the first line of the method and see if you're passing in all the other fields?

Comment: @Amarnasan Nope. Nothing out of the ordinary for email.

Comment: @milo526 Sure, it's in the edit.

Comment: @SteD Sure thing. It's also in the edit.

Comment: i think you are using auth try to pass email in header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't cycling errors in my markup.

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
        {{ $errors->first() }}
        <a href="#" class="alert-close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
    </div>
@endif
```

the reason why I didn't realize that is because my template page also has an email field named email (for login), and was cycling errors for it. So only the form's email, which had the same name, was redirecting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type of the input to email instead of text. You probably entered a text value when you made the submit, Laravel already has a validation for the email type

```
<div class="border-bot">
            <input class="submitArtTitle" type="text" maxlength="255" name="email"  placeholder="Email">
        </div>
```

TO

```
<div class="border-bot">
            <input class="submitArtTitle" type="email" maxlength="255" name="email"  placeholder="Email">
        </div>
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything. I'd like to point out that the email one is the only one that works, so I'm not sure changing it will do anything.

Comment: $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|alpha_num|max:40|min:2',            
        'country' => 'required|alpha_num|max:100|min:2',                        
        'body' => 'required|string|max:2000',
        'mature' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
    ]);   you might want to at least change it and see because the controller is looking for an email type

Comment: That's not how it works. Even with type="text", it just looks to make sure it's a valid email format. So if you wrote "test@gmail" it would return an error (and it does I just checked), but if you wrote "test@gmail.com" it works fine.

Comment: Ok then, try to use fillable array in your model, or check if the email is included in the fillable array